# XMPP/jabber with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io, xmpp, ejabberd

I am trying to build a chat application, After a fair amount of research on the internet, I have considered two of the following options :

1. ejabberd
2. Node.js with socket.io

Since XMPP offers a huge number of ready made features, I may have to reinvent many stuff in socket.io, which makes me more inclined towards the ejabberd.

However, XMPP's Documentation does not mention mongo as a supported Database. Please suggest a solution since I am restricted to use only mongo on my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ejabberd,  uses an internal native database (http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/#database-and-ldap-configuration) by default. So you dont have to install a separate DB instance in this case.